# Fabric set environment variable globally

Tags: python, fabric

I am writing a fabfile that I want to include an environment variable for the virtualenv that I'm using for development. I don't want to have to put

```
with shell_env(venv=VIRTUALENV):
    ...
```

in every single function. I'd like to be able to add this at the beginning of the file and have it apply to all tasks globally. Is there a way to do this?

For example, I have the tasks

```
def setup_dev_env():
    with shell_env(venv=VIRTUALENV):
        local('virtualenv $(venv)')
        with prefix('workon $(venv)'):
            local('pip install -r requirements.txt')
        test()

def test():
    with shell_env(venv=VIRTUALENV):
        with prefix('workon $(vnenv)'):
            local('python3 manage.py test')
```

and it would be nice if I didn't have to repeat exactly the same line at the beginning of both functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is considered a hack of [`command_prefixes`](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.10/usage/env.html#command-prefixes) but it works:

```
env.command_prefixes=["export myvar='Hello world'",]
def echo_env():
    run(r"echo $myvar")
```

Output:

```
C:\Users\swozn\PycharmProjects\aaetuea>fab echo_env
[swozn@localhost] Executing task 'echo_env'
[swozn@localhost] run: echo $myvar
[swozn@localhost] out: Hello world
```

The advantage is that it is impossible to forget, because it is automatically prepended to all your commands.

Comment: A bit, but i wouldnt count it against you since usually you would want environment variables to be global

Answer (score 1):

If you look at `prefix()` and `shell_env()` - you'll notice that they just use `_setenv({..})` you can combine everything with `settings()` and put that in a function and all it once or just have it all in one line.. up to you.

https://github.com/fabric/fabric/blob/5217b12f8aca3bc071206f7f4168e62c003509d1/fabric/context_managers.py#L370

https://github.com/fabric/fabric/blob/5217b12f8aca3bc071206f7f4168e62c003509d1/fabric/context_managers.py#L160

https://github.com/fabric/fabric/blob/5217b12f8aca3bc071206f7f4168e62c003509d1/fabric/context_managers.py#L443

if will look something like:

```
def setup_dev_env():
    with settings(..all your options..):
        local(..your command...)
```

or if you really want to be cool:

```
@with_settings(..all your same options from before..)
def setup_dev_env():
   local(..command..)
```