# Python - How to set env.variables in Fabric module

Tags: python, networking, raspberry-pi, fabric

I'm trying to run commands in parallel on a few raspberry Pis using the Fabric module. I've read the documentation but I'm still a bit confused.

```
import fabric

env.hosts = [
    "pi@192.168.3.151", 
    "pi@192.168.3.123"
]

env.password = "Raspberry"

@parallel
def command(cmd):
    sudo(cmd)

command("touch /Desktop/new_filename.txt")
```

When I run that code I get the error `env is not defined`, how am I supposed to define env here to use those hosts? The documentation is beyond me at this stage.

Comment: from fabric import *

Comment: Also checkout this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33258802/fabric-set-environment-variable-globally

Comment: @veri_pudcha_coder - Even using `from fabric import *` I receive the same error

Comment: @ManojJadhav Is there not a file somewhere I need to edit to set the env.hosts or something? My console is outputting the `env` isn't defined so I don't think that code would work for me, I would receive the same error

Comment: You can import env from api as well `from fabric.api import env` may be this help.

Comment: I think the `fabric.api` might have been an older version of fabric. Importing `fabric.api` instead of just `fabric` gives me an error

Comment: What version of fabric are you using?

Answer (score 1):

The below should work for you:

```
from fabric.context_managers import env
from fabric.decorators import task
from fabric.tasks import execute

env.hosts = [
    "pi@192.168.3.151", 
    "pi@192.168.3.123"
]

env.password = "Raspberry"

@task
def command(cmd):
    sudo(cmd)

execute('command', "touch /Desktop/new_filename.txt")
```

Note the two things we did here:  (1) import what we need and (2) make sure to use the task / execute structure to pick up run-time changes to the env.

Comment: I finally got around to testing this out and unfortunately none of those modules seem to exist for me even though plain old `fabric` imports fine